# Extract a string from an object inside an array: PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, object

I'm writing a PHP plugin and need to extract a string from an object which is inside an array.

```
var_dump($data)
```

outputs:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#380 (53) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["firstname"]=> string(6) "John" 
        ["lastname"]=> string(6) "Doe" 
        ["email"]=> string(31) "johndoe@email.com" 
    } 
}
```

I want to return:

```
johndoe@mail.com
```

My research has turned up functions such as unserialize, array_map, array_slice, and array_column, but I haven't found the right function or combination of functions that work together (nor do I understand them enough) to just return a simple string from an object inside an array. Can anyone provide me with some guidance?

Edit: This isn't the same question as the one referenced as "the exact same question." The other one asks simply how to access an array (answer: $array[0]), and my question asked how to access an object INSIDE an array (answer: $array[0]->text).

Comment: just echo `$data[0]->email`

Comment: Programming works by composition. If you know how to access an array element, and you know how to access an object property, just put them together to access a property of an array element.

Comment: I don't really get the question. Is something going to dynamic, such as the array structure or object key names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
$data[0]->firstname
```

Maybe:

```
$arr = get_object_vars($data[0]);
$arr['firstname'];
```

Example:

```
$obj = (object) array('x' => 'foo');
$arr = [$obj];

print($arr[0]->x);
```

You will get: `foo`